# Derive value in a table column from other tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have a revenue table with column amount and expense table with column tax and a profit table with column total, how do I derive the value into profit table by calculating amount minus profit, in Ruby on Rails 3

Comment: Think about "model", not "table"

Comment: Billy Chan can you please elaborate ?

Comment: Table is only the storage of model. Model contains all domain logic.

Comment: Can you not just calculate the profit on the fly (ie: revenue - expenses = profit)? Is there a reason you need a table to store this calculated value?